# imagemagick convert - compress all files in the directory

Tags: bash, shell-script, imagemagick

I run the following command to compress jpg file:

```
convert -strip -interlace Plane -gaussian-blur 0.05 -quality 85% source.jpg result.jpg
```

How to execute it for all jpg files in the directory where compressed file name will be define this way: Old_Name_Compressed.jpg

Comment: What have you tried?  How did it not work as expected or intended?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using `find` and execute `convert` command for each file found.

```
find . -type f -name '*.jpg' -exec bash -c 'convert -strip -interlace Plane -gaussian-blur 0.05 -quality 85% "$1" "${1%.jpg}_compressed.jpg" ' bash  {} \;
```

`${parameter%suffix}` is known as [bash-parameter-expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html), that strips shortest *suffix* from its *parameter*.